# Up/Left arrow keys + another key doesn't 'work'

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, gaming, input-device

I hope I'm right in thinking this is the site where you post general computer-related problems...

A problem I have when playing games (since you won't be pressing multiple keys simultaneously anytime else) is that when I press and hold Up/Left keys together with another key, that last key fails to 'work' or it hinders the arrow keys and doesn't let them work. This doesn't happen with any other arrow key combination, e.g. Up/Right or Down/Left.

The weird thing is that same thing happens when I'm using WASD instead of the arrow keys! Meaning W+A+smth else doesn't work. Perhaps this problem is for all such sets of four keys.

If someone knows what my problem is, I'd appreciate the help.
(My reflexes are fast so I can circumvent this obstacle, but it's quite annoying and totally unnecessary)

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times. Please read [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I do face same issue when playing fifa. I have try anything solution including installing latest driver and reinstalling the game.  But still doesn't work. BUT, later I switch back to basic hp keyboard then the problem gone.

Comment: Well, I have the prob both on my laptop's keyboard, and my seperate A4tech usb keyboard :-/

Comment: Have you tried another keyboard ?

Comment: I have this problem with pretty much all games. Like when crouching and moving left and forward in games like counter strike or unreal tournament series. (i know i didnt have this prob on my old pc, so it's a system prob) funny thing is, i was playing a game yesterday, and i could easily use up+left+ctrl+alt! Dunno what's up...